# Where to ask questions about RothC

Tags: r

I need to ask my questions about the RothC model.
RothC estimates the Carbon input into the soil for the next 20 years using a forward-phase R script.
I need to estimate Carbon for the next 40 or even 500 years.
When I change the years by more than 20 years, Carbon input declines. I expect an increase, although a little, and not a decrease.
Where can I ask this question?

Comment: Here is fine, but please edit your question to include the specific coding question you are looking to answer and use appropriate tags

Comment: An alternative (for the Theory behind it) is on [stats.se], which is technically more appropriate (but many questions stick here on SO anyway).

Comment: When I googled `"cran" rothc` (quotes important), one of the first returns for me was the [`SoilR`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SoilR/) package, I suggest you look at that package for looking into RothC in R.